# how to get the last modified date for old MS-office files, e.g. .xls and .doc files

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is there any APIs in the POI to read out the last modified date for old office files?

I am using poi 4.1.0, actually I am able to read out the last modified date for .xlsx and .docx files but also with a small problem: with getModifiedPropertyString() it returns a correct string value but with getModifiedProperty() it returns a Optional date always with empty value.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
POIXMLProperties props = new POIXMLProperties(pkg);
PackagePropertiesPart ppropsPart = props.getCoreProperties().getUnderlyingProperties();
Optional<Date> date = ppropsPart.*getModifiedProperty()*;
        
System.out.println(date);
```

For this above code for .xlsx and .docx files, the result is: Optional.empty

Comment: Isn't it the same as typical `File.lastModified()`? Do you even need POI for that?

Comment: No. It is not the same for last modified in office documents and last modified in file system. Consider some one has saved a word document last year, and this document is copied to somewhere via JAVA InputStream/OutputStream now, in this case, the last modified date in office property will still remain as last year but the last modified date in file system "File.lastModified()" will be today.

Comment: What's wrong with [reading and following the Apache POI documentation on the topic](https://poi.apache.org/components/hpsf/how-to.html#sec1)?

Comment: Well, thank you very much. I was not aware that there is POIFS documentation, I can read out the last modified date for xls and doc files now.